# Why doesn't django redirect to new url using drag-and-drop file upload?

Tags: html, django, drag-and-drop, redirect

I want to incorporate a drag-and-drop to upload files using Django and HTML. I am able to upload the file and save it to the model "Document". After that, I want to be redirected to 'user:datapreparation', which will display the dataframe in a new page. However, I am not redirected and I stay on the same page ("**user:userform**").

Do you perhaps know why I am not redirected to datapreparation'?

Hereby the code.
Thank you for your help!

### View:

```
class FileUploadView(View):
    form_class = DocumentForm
    template_name = 'user/model_form_upload.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):

        document_name = str(request.FILES['file'])

        if request.FILES['file'].size < 31457280:  # max 30 mbs allowed
            form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
            document_type = str(document_name.rsplit(".", 1)[1])
            valid_document_types = ["txt", "csv", "xlsx"]
            if document_type in valid_document_types:

                a = Document.objects.all()[0]
                a.file = request.FILES['file']
                a.description = document_name
                a.save()
                return redirect('user:datapreparation')
```

### Models:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

### URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'user'

urlpatterns = [
    # upload
    url(r'^upload/$', views.FileUploadView.as_view(), name='userform'),
    # data preparation - dataframe creation
    url(r'^datapreparation/$', views.DataPreparation.as_view(), name='datapreparation'),
]
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="upload"></div>
    <form class="dropzone" action="{% url 'user:datapreparation' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dropzone">{% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            Drop files here
        </div>
    </form>


<script>
(function() {

        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');


        dropzone.ondrop=function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        this.className='dropzone';

        var data = new FormData(form);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var file = ev.dataTransfer.files[0]
        console.log(file)

        xhr.open('POST', "/user/upload/")
        data.append('file', file)
        xhr.send(data)
        };

        dropzone.ondragover = function () {
            this.className = "dropzone dragover";
            return false;
        };

        dropzone.ondragleave = function () {
            this.className = 'dropzone';
            return false;
        };
    }());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from django is being handled by the javascript, so you you could return the URL in the django view (using for example the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) method) and then `window.location.href` in the javascript.
You can check how to add a callback to XMLHttpRequest [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response#Example)

Comment: Thank you kindly!
After "xhr.send(data)" I've added the following line:
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "{% url 'user:datapreparation' %}" }, 1000);
Where the setTimeout was needed to give the Django back-end time to process the file (works up to my limit of 30mbs). 

I don't know if this was what exactly you meant, but it did the job for me!

Comment: The best way is using the callback mentioned. That way, the callback is executed when the django view returns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the reverse mechanism on your redirect.

```
from django.urls import reverse
return redirect(reverse('user:datapreparation'))
```